The feature 'Timesheets' required to access this page is not enabled in this account
I am trying to create a Time Entry record using SuiteScript. But it returns an error message "The feature 'Timesheets' required to access this page is not enabled in this account." when executing the record.save() line. Is there a way to solve this problem and create a Time Entry record using SuiteScript?
I would also like to know how to enter hour, minutes and seconds in the "Duration" field. I can't enter values like "15:00:00" in setValue() of 'hours' field
var rec = record.create(
            {
                type: record.Type.TIME_ENTRY, 
                isDynamic: true
            }
        );
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'employee',
            value: 1962,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'customer',
            value: 2069,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'casetaskevent',
            value: 1227,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'hours',
            value: 5,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        var trackTime = rec.save(); //When executing this line, the error shows.

